# Can't fetch an API depending on backend cookie (credentialed API route) in Next.js

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, next.js, jwt

Here are the response headers:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved the problem, after 6 days of brutality, the answer to my problem was the path i send my cookie should match the path on the frontend that i fetch the api that depends on this cookie so i set a cookie and set its path to `'/'` and on the frontend after logging in i get directed to `"/"` on the frontend and here i use useEffect to fetch the cookie from the `"/"` route on the backend.